# Mapping won't work when cursor is at the last character of the buffer

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following mapping set in `vimrc` that saves the file and copy its content to clipboard:

```
:map <F3> :w<CR>gg<S-V>G"*y
```

It does what I want, except when I have the cursor positioned at the last character of the buffer. Why is this?

Comment: I would just use `:nnoremap <f4> :%y+`

Comment: Does it help if you write `ggVG` instead of `<S-V>`? Not sure why it would matter, but generally no reason to do the `<S-` version.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt. Elegant, thanks.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. Without the ```<S-``` it worked. I can see no reason to use it either. I must have meant to "capitalize" ```V``` by mistake.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble or Fred it could be worth adding and answer to with `V` instead of `<S-V>` to reduce the number of unanswered questions and to help future reader know there is a working solution.

Comment: @statox indeed, thank you for the reminder

Answer (score 3):

To fix the mapping, use `V` instead of `<S-V>`.

But as Christian points out in the comments, a simpler version exists:

```
nnoremap <f4> :write | %yank +<cr>
```